# Android/MySQL Runtime error

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

Im attempting to insert into a MySQL database, and the code works and does insert but instantly crashed, cant see the issue.

> **applications.loginandregister E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: applications.loginandregister, PID: 2545
>                                                                                android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@5aa47b4 is not valid; is your activity
>   running?
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:849)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:337)
>                                                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:350)
>                                                                                    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1113)
>                                                                                    at
>   applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.display(BackgroundTask.java:206)
>                                                                                    at
>   applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:192)
>                                                                                    at
>   applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:32)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)**

```
package applications.loginandregister;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.renderscript.ScriptGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.Buffer;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by Mitch on 2016-06-04.
 */
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    Context context;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("flag","0");
        editor.commit();

        String urlRegistration = "http://domain.com/LoginAndRegister-register.php";
        String urlLogin  = "http://domain.com/LoginAndRegister-login.php";
        String task = params[0];

        if(task.equals("register")){
            String regName = params[1];
            String regEmail = params[2];
            String regPassword = params[3];



            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlRegistration);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                String myData = URLEncoder.encode("identifier_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regName,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regPassword,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(myData);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();

                editor.putString("flag","register");
                editor.commit();
                return "Successfully Registered " + regName;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        if(task.equals("login")){
            String loginEmail = params[1];
            String loginPassword = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlLogin);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                //send the email and password to the database
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                String myData = URLEncoder.encode("identifier_loginEmail","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(loginEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_loginPassword","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(loginPassword,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(myData);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                //get response from the database
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String dataResponse = "";
                String inputLine = "";
                while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    dataResponse += inputLine;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                System.out.println(dataResponse);

                editor.putString("flag","login");
                editor.commit();
                return  dataResponse;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    //This method willbe called when doInBackground completes... and it will return the completion string which
    //will display this toast.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        String flag = preferences.getString("flag","0");


        if(flag.equals("register")) {
            Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(flag.equals("login"))
        {
            String test = "false";
            String name = "";
            String email = "";
            String[] serverResponse = s.split(",");


            test = serverResponse[0];
            name = serverResponse[1];
            email = serverResponse[2];
            //display("Message ",serverResponse[2]);

            if(test.equals("true"))
            {

               editor.putString("name",name);
               editor.commit();
               editor.putString("email",email);
               editor.commit();
               Intent intent = new Intent(context,LogginIn.class);
               context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
               display("Login Failed...", "That email and password do not match our records :(.");
            }
        }

        else
       {
           display("Login Failed...","Something weird happened :(.");
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    public void display(String title, String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

It seems that I comment out **finish();** it works but still not right shows login failed something weird happend.

Here is the registration page

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etName, etEmail, etPassword;
    String name, email, password;
    Button btnRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewEmail);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewPassword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewRegister);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                name = etName.getText().toString();
                email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                String task = "register";
                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(Register.this);
                backgroundTask.execute(task,name, email, password);
                //finish();


            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: A Backgroundtask can not open a dialog window i guess!

Comment: Is ok with login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show the dialog on UI thread.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              display("Login Failed...","Something weird happened :(.");  
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not sure why there is a problem - could you elaborate

Comment: you are running a UI operation in the background thread thus it's crashing.